# django pagination returns all data after clicking any page in search result

Tags: django, pagination

I paginate search result. At first, query set gives me perfect result and initial page numbers indicate correctly, but when click to any page number, it accepts search key as null and get all data from db.
here is the code

```
def search(request):
    searchKey = request.POST.get("key", "")
    searchRequestsInitial = ScRequests.objects.filter(description__contains=searchKey)
    searchCount = searchRequestsInitial.count()

    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    paginator = Paginator(searchRequestsInitial, 10)

    try:
        searchRequests = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        searchRequests = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        searchRequests = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    context = {'searchRequests':searchRequests,'searchCount':searchCount,'searchKey':searchKey}
    template = "searchResult.html"
    return render(request,template,context)
```

in template:

```
    <tbody>
    {% if searchRequests %}
       {% for searchRequest in searchRequests %}
        <tr>
          <td>{{searchRequest.description|convert_utf8|shortName}}</td>
          <td>{{searchRequest.title|convert_utf8|shortName}}</td>
          <td>{{searchRequest.sender}}</td>
        </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}  
      </tbody>
    </table>

    {% if searchRequests.has_other_pages %}
      <ul class="pagination">
        {% if searchRequests.has_previous %}
          <li><a href="?page={{ searchRequests.previous_page_number }}">&laquo;</a></li>
        {% else %}
          <li class="disabled"><span>&laquo;</span></li>
        {% endif %}
        {% for i in searchRequests.paginator.page_range %}
          {% if searchRequests.number == i %}
            <li class="active"><span>{{ i }} <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></span></li>
          {% else %}
            <li><a href="?page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        {% if searchRequests.has_next %}
          <li><a href="?page={{ searchRequests.next_page_number }}">&raquo;</a></li>
        {% else %}
          <li class="disabled"><span>&raquo;</span></li>
        {% endif %}
      </ul>
    {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forget to add `key` argument to the url:

```
<li><a href="?page={{ searchRequests.previous_page_number }}">&laquo;</a></li>
```

so when you click link `key` value sets to null.
Change links like this:

```
<li><a href="?page={{ searchRequests.previous_page_number }}&key={{ searchKey }}">&laquo;</a></li>
```

**UPDATE**

Also when you open page via link you are using GET, so add also this:

```
searchKey = request.POST.get("key", "")
if not searchKey:
    searchKey = request.GET.get("key", "")
```

it will set key from request's GET if POST is empty.

But instead of this you can change search form method to GET, and now you can simply check GET argument:

```
searchKey = request.GET.get("key", "")
```